# Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. (Every 10 sec in my Event Log)

Tags: security, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services

I got the following INFO in my event log every 10 sec, any idea what does it mean? and why getting this info?

Windows 2003, managed by 1 user (me) and I only have the account.

Event Log Message:

"Remote session from client name a exceeded the maximum allowed failed logon attempts. The session was forcibly terminated."

[image: EventLog]

Many Thanks.

Comment: This question should go to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  Rebooted the server and the problem is gone.  I suspect that "I" was the "attacker" and something with RDP was glitched out.